# Python | как и чем открыть .doc файл и прочитать оттуда таблицу?

Tags: python, файлы, doc

Вот простой пример кода (у меня он чуть сложнее из-за красочного вывода таблицы)

Так вот, код прекрасно работает с .docx файлами, но не хочет с .doc

Как исправить?

```
from docx import Document


word_doc = Document('file.doc')
table = word_doc.tables[0]
for row in table.rows:
   text = row.cells[0].text
   print(text)
```